# Angular 7 button submit refresh the page

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

Good day.

I am following this tutorial

```
https://www.tutsmake.com/new-angular-7-upload-file-image-example/
```

Which will upload a file

i Created a `fileupload` component

modified the `app.module.ts` file

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      HttpClientModule
   ],
```

As of now this is the code for the `fileupload.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fileupload',
  templateUrl: './fileupload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileupload.component.css']
})
export class FileuploadComponent implements OnInit {
  fileData: File = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Called');
  }

}
```

And this is my `fileupload.component.htnl`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="image"  />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

But why does the `onSubmit()` is not called?

When i press the submit button. The website refresh it self. And the command is not called. In the console of the chrome browser. It didn't even log the `'Called'` It didn't even have an error. So im really confused why does it doesn't call the function

I tried this and it still refresh the page

```
<form ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
      <input type="file" name="image"  />
  </div>
  <div >
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And if i use this

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
      <input type="file" name="image"  />
  </div>
  <div >
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I received an error like this

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
```

How to i properly solve this?

Thank you

Comment: You have to add or `[ngForm]` directive or `[formGroup]` directive. Only those provide event called `ngSubmit`

Comment: Any errors in console? It should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-97w8fo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: If there is any outer form around your `fileuploadComponent` it may be called. Therefore, if this outer form has an `action=""` it will refresh page

Comment: I updated the question. And kindly help me solve the problem

Comment: @Sergey can you please post your comment as answer. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've asked me to post my comment as an answer.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-97w8fo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I guess you lack of imported `FormsModule` for `[ngForm]` or `ReactiveFormsModule` for `[formGroup]`.

Actually it's enough to just import `FormsModule` and this will automatically add `ngForm` to your `<form>` thus enabling `(ngSubmit)` event availability on `<form>`

Comment: Actually the link you provided really help me. I checked the code and see whats is missing with mine. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Try using type="submit" inside button tag like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `type="submit"` is a default attribute - if the button has no `type`, it has `type="submit"` set implicitly.

Comment: Yes I missed that point, With your updated question Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form':

You need to initialise the form first with the formControls and bind them, follow this for more details:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance